# Which instance will be called in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have 2 base classes (`B1` and `B2`) which are derived from common Base class(B), where they have a common variable (let: `int x;` from base B), in 1st base `x=0`, in the 2nd base `x=10` (default values given in B1,B2 constructors).

Now if I derive one more class (`class D : virtual public B1, virtual public B2{}`).

Here only one copy of `x` will be available as per virtual concept, now if I try to access `x` value with derived class object which instance of `x` I will get in O/p (`x=0` or `x=10`), and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Here only one copy of x will be available as per virtual concept"_ That's not true.

Comment: sorry guys, I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the right place ( if you are not further deriving ) to use virtual base class. Perhaps you are mixing concepts.

```
class A;
class B : virtual public A
class C : virtual public A
class D : public B, public C
```

In this case it's meaningful to make base classes virtual as there are two paths to class A when you see through D.

Your case is :-

```
class B1
{
 public:
    int x;
};

class B2
{
  public :
     int x;
};

class D : public B1, publicB2
{
  public :
     void accessBase ()
     {
       this->x;             //error as ambigous.
       this->B1::x;         //fine it's B1's x.
       this->B2::x;         //fine it's B2's x.
     }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> here only one copy of x will be available as per virtual concept

No - the use of `virtual` bases ensures there's only one copy of `B1` and one of `B2`, but there's only been one listed in the inheritance heirarchy anyway so the "virtuality" of the bases is irrelevant to the functionality here.  Each base is a distinct class and both still have distinct `x` members.  Therefore, you must disambiguate which you plan to use just as if the bases weren't `virtual`, using `B1::x` or `B2::x`.

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B1 { int x; };
struct B2 { int x; };
struct D : virtual B1, virtual B2 { };

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.B1::x = 2;
    d.B2::x = 4;
    std::cout << d.B1::x << ' ' << d.B2::x << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 4
```

That shows they're independent variables.  See the code running [here](http://ideone.com/oksygR)

Answer (score 1):

> Here only one copy of `x` will be available as per virtual concept

Here is the fundamental problem with your question's premise, because that's *not true*.

Unrelated bases cannot be "merged" just because you mark them `virtual`. If both `B1` and `B2` themselves derived from some `VeryBase`, then virtually deriving from `B1` and `B2` means you'd only have one copy of `VeryBase`:

```
                 VeryBase
                  /    \
                 /      \
                B1      B2    (inherited virtually)
                 \      /
                  \    /
                   \  /
                    \/
                     D
```

as opposed to:

```
          VeryBase      VeryBase
              \            /
               \          /
                B1      B2    (inherited normally)
                 \      /
                  \    /
                   \  /
                    \/
                     D
```

But that's not what you're doing here at all. There's no `VeryBase` — just two, independent, bases:

```
                B1      B2    (inherited normally or virtually; it doesn't matter)
                 \      /
                  \    /
                   \  /
                    \/
                     D
```

In this instance, your `virtual` inheritance is not making any difference at all, so you still have two `int x` members and you can access them independently in the usual way:

```
void D::foo()
{
   std::cout << B1::x << ' ' B2::x << std::endl;
}
```